# How to trigger change event for angular ui-select directive for unit tests?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to test my code that uses an ui-select directive:

```
<ui-select class="firstSelect"
        ng-model="singleFilter.selectedField" 
        ng-disabled="vm.filterDisabled" 
        on-select="vm.itemSelected(singleFilter)"                      
        theme="bootstrap">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="...">
              {{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="field in singleFilter.fields | filter: $select.search">
                    <span ng-bind-html="field.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

The question is: How can I trigger the change event on this control, when unit testing my code that uses this directive ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same frustration.  I found in the [ui-select spec](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/test/select.spec.js) that executing the `on-select` function requires calling `$timeout.flush()` after clicking one of the choice items.

Something like this (don't forget to inject $timeout):

```
compiledUiSelectEl.find('.ui-select-choices-row-inner')[0].click();
scope.$digest();
$timeout.flush();
```

And including the relevant portions of the test from [ui-select spec](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/test/select.spec.js)

```
function compileTemplate(template) {
  var el = $compile(angular.element(template))(scope);
  scope.$digest();
  return el;
}

function clickItem(el, text) {

  if (!isDropdownOpened(el)) {
    openDropdown(el);
  }

  $(el).find('.ui-select-choices-row div:contains("' + text + '")').click();
  scope.$digest();
}


it('should invoke select callback on select', function () {

  scope.onSelectFn = function ($item, $model, $label) {
    scope.$item = $item;
    scope.$model = $model;
  };
  var el = compileTemplate(
    '<ui-select on-select="onSelectFn($item, $model)" ng-model="selection.selected"> \
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match> \
      <ui-select-choices repeat="person.name as person in people | filter: $select.search"> \
        <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div> \
        <div ng-bind-html="person.email | highlight: $select.search"></div> \
      </ui-select-choices> \
    </ui-select>'
  );

  expect(scope.$item).toBeFalsy();
  expect(scope.$model).toBeFalsy();

  clickItem(el, 'Samantha');
  $timeout.flush();


  expect(scope.selection.selected).toBe('Samantha');

  expect(scope.$item).toEqual(scope.people[5]);
  expect(scope.$model).toEqual('Samantha');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test should just be calling the itemSelected function directly.  So once you create an instance of the controller in the unit test just call:

```
vm.itemSelected(mockData);
```

Comment: I already do that. But I would like to know that the on-select is correctly wired.